# returning certain column in javascript

Tags: javascript

guys i know it is dummy question but i spent lot of hours and didn't reach ... i have a code that `return all columns names in first row` .. here is my code

```
this.columns = $.map(this.data[0], function(item, key) {
    return key;
});
```

what if i want to return the index of the column named "`id` ?? .. any suggestions ?? .. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult without knowing what the `this.data` array looks like but this might be what you're looking for:

**Note**: I'm just assuming that `this.data` is an array of column names

```
var data = [ ["id", "col2", "col3"] ];
this.columns = $.map(data[0], function(item, key) {
  if (item === "id") {
    return key;
  }
});
```

You can check out a simple example I setup here [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jw5Lfyow/2/)